# How to update checked out folder with longer paths than 255 characters using SVN on Windows?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I checked out a huge project using TortoiseSVN and it worked fine and I can even update it. But when I try to update it using the command line SlikSVN client it tries to access a relative path just short of 255 characters. The absolute path would be much longer than 255 characters.

It stops updating with this error:

`svn: Kann Datei »very\long\path\.svn\text-base\LongClassName.java.svn-base« nicht öffnen: The system cannot find the path specified.`
The German translates roughly to "Can't open file"

Is it possible to update this folder from a batch file at all or do I have to use Eclipse with Subversive or TortoiseSVN which seem like they don't have the 255 character limitation but can't be used in a batch file?

Comment: FYI, it's not quite a Subversion limitation. Windows has 2 APIs for handling file paths, one of which has a limit of about 215 characters (it's a bit less than 255), the other can handle much longer paths. APR (which handles the I/O for Subversion) uses the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `subst` to shorten the path and use svn with the shortened path:

```
subst X:\ D:\development\projects\yourlongpath\..
```

I got a similar issue in a recent project and was able to solve it this way.

**Edit**
To update the project you can use the new mapping:

```
svn update X:\
```